# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtwebkit

I am porting code from qt4 to qt5. I added the following line to my `.pro` file, [as suggested](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Transition_from_Qt_4.x_to_Qt5):

```
QT += webkitwidgets
```

However, when I run `qmake`, I get the this error:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets
```

I am developing on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and installed Qt [as described](https://askubuntu.com/questions/279421/how-can-i-install-qt-5-x-on-12-04-lts).

Comment: how to fix this in macOS - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72589559/mac-os-warning-project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-webkitwidgets?noredirect=1#comment128228415_72589559

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You need to install the webkitwidgets library.

On Ubuntu, try this in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev
```

On Fedora, the package has a different name, thus try:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-qtwebkit-devel
```

Or on Fedora, via dnf:

```
sudo dnf install qt5-qtwebkit-devel
```

Comment: Is there any solution for OS X?

Comment: Hey, i tried this but it still throws the same error. Is there a solution?

Comment: What about Windows?

Comment: @Muadh Programmer: The question stated that a solution for Ubuntu is wanted, so my answer is for that OS. However, the other answers address Windows. If you have questions concerning their solutions, you can comment on their answers.

Comment: how to fix this in macOS - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72589559/mac-os-warning-project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-webkitwidgets?noredirect=1#comment128228415_72589559

Answer (score 12):

If you need to install the webkit* Windows library for Qt 5.7 you should compile it manually because in new version webkit (WebView?) replaced by WebEngine.

Read about Qt 5.7 release (comments): http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/06/16/qt-5-7-released/

Build sequence (static OR shared):

1) Download Qt 5.7.0 sources: http://download.qt.io/community_releases/5.7/5.7.0/

2) Download required tools: ActiveState Perl (binary), Python (binary), Ruby (binary), GnuWin Bison (binary), GPref (binary), Grep (binary), WinFlex, LibIconv, make (binary), sqlite (source!), ICU (source), windows msys (binary) (unix like shell with the tools), mingw-w64 (bin+dev) for build Qt with QtWebKit, see link on: https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingQtOnWindows

3) After download ICU source into C:\icu\icu. Open msys QT mingw console shell by open Start windows menu (msys should be downloaded and installed) and search or use fast search. In opened console start configure script and then compile and install:

> $ cd C:\icu\icu\source
>
> $ ./runConfigureICU
>
> $ set PATH=%PATH%;C:\msys\1.0\bin\
>
> $ make.exe
>
> $ make.exe install

4) Build Qt with(!) ICU support (set "-icu" to configure) see compile script below. Change PATH to your environment.

Directory structure:

- C:\Qt\5.7.0 - download binary version of Qt 5.7.0 here
- C:\Qt\5.7.0n - directory for new (compiled) version of 5.7.0 (just make dir)
- C:\Qt\Src - download source of Qt 5.7.0 here

C:\Qt\Src\qtbase\compile.bat

```
set INCLUDE=C:\icu\icu\dist\include
set LIB=C:\icu\icu\dist\lib
set QTDIR=C:\Qt\5.7.0n
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\5.7\mingw53_32\bin;C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin;C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0\Tools\mingw530_32\bin;C:\Qt\Src\qtbase\bin;C:\Program Files (X86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:\winflex;C:\Ruby23-x64\bin;C:\Python27;C:\mingw-w64\i686-1\mingw32\bin;C:\icu\bin
set QMAKESPEC=win32-g++
set BUILD_DIR=C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0n
call C:\Qt\Src\qtbase\configure.bat -prefix %BUILD_DIR% -platform %QMAKESPEC% -confirm-license -debug-and-release -opensource -opengl desktop -no-compile-examples -icu -I C:/icu/icu/dist/include -L C:/icu/icu/dist/lib
jom.exe -j 4
pause
```

Run command in exmaple in Windows Power Shell:

> $ cd C:\Qt\Src\qtbase
>
> $ ./compile.bat

After pass through compile use it to install files in the BUILD_DIR (install Qt files):

> $ C:\mingw-w64\i686-1\mingw32\bin\mingw32-make.exe install

Qt should start to install

5) Download Qtwebkit sources to C:\Qt\Src\qtwebkit. Use compile script below to compile the qtwebkit using new Qt 5.7.0 build with files in C:\Qt\5.7.0n with ICU.

C:\Qt\Src\qtwebkit\Tools\Scripts\compile.bat

```
set INCLUDE=C:\sqlite
set LIBS=C:\sqlite
set SQLITE3SRCDIR=C:\sqlite
set QTDIR=C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0n
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0n\bin;C:\Qt\Src\qtbase\bin;C:\winflex;C:\Ruby23-x64\bin;C:\Python27;C:\mingw-w64\i686-1\mingw32\bin;C:\icu\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin
set QMAKESPEC=win32-g++
call perl.exe .\build-webkit --qt --release
```

Compile the qtwebkit:

> $ cd C:\Qt\Src\qtwebkit\Tools\Scripts
>
> $ ./compile.bat
>
> $ cd C:\Qt\Src\qtwebkit\WebKitBuild\Release
>
> $ C:\mingw-w64\i686-1\mingw32\bin\mingw32-make.exe install

It should be possible to compile your application with the qtwebkit after successfull compile and install.

BUILD QT FOR STATIC

Edit file C:\Qt\Src\qtbase\compile.bat and pass through build.

```
...
call C:\Qt\Src\qtbase\configure.bat -prefix %BUILD_DIR% -platform %QMAKESPEC% -confirm-license -debug-and-release -opensource -opengl desktop -static -no-compile-examples -icu
echo "QMAKE_FLAGS += -static -static-libgcc" >> .mkspecs/%QMAKESPEC%/qmake.conf
...
```

POSSIBLE ERRORS

1) While build qtwebkit: `"fatal error: unicode/uchar.h: No such file or directory"`

Check that your Qt 5.7.0n build with ICU. IT also could notify you about "ICU required" at configure in qtwebkit.

2) `flex: unknown flag '-'.  For usage, try`

You should use correct version of Flex that is "win_flex" in this case. You should rename files to use win_flex instead of just flex (and bison).

> 1) rename C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\flex.exe to some unused name.
>
> 2) rename C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\bison.exe to some unused name.
>
> 3) rename C:\winflex\win_bison.exe to bison.exe.

3) While build qtwebkit: `"fatal error: sqlite3.h: No such file or directory"`

Edit file C:\Qt\Src\qtwebkit\Tools\Scripts\compile.bat and check for correct path to sqlite:

```
set SQLITE3SRCDIR=C:\(path to some SQLITE .h/source files)
```

4) `skipping incompatible ... when searching for ...`

You should download right library arch (32bit or 64bit)

5) `View.cpp ... undefined reference to WKPageCanGoBack`

Could happens when pass through some test or MiniBrowser. You can search in files for the "UIProcess/API/qt" and "MiniBroswer" and remove it from
Makefile's and some other files and then start build again.

LINKS

> Build Qt5: https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git Qt WebKit build
>
> like how to: https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingQtOnWindows ICU
>
> build with GNU: https://wiki.qt.io/Compiling-ICU-with-MinGW

Comment: Hello, I'm stuck at C:\Qt\Src\qtbase\compile.bat
this fails with "C:\qt5.7-source\qtbase>jom.exe -j 4
Error: File Makefile doesn't exist." Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: app developer 27, make sure that the previous command in the bat file successfully done:
"call C:\Qt\Src\qtbase\configure.bat -prefix %BUILD_DIR% -platform %QMAKESPEC% -confirm-license -debug-and-release -opensource -opengl desktop -no-compile-examples -icu -I C:/icu/icu/dist/include -L C:/icu/icu/dist/lib"

Comment: thank you for your answer! Now I think got a bit further with qtbase\compile.bat. Do you have any idea what might cause the newest error "The syntax of the command is incorrect."? http://pastebin.com/pCLXvs22

Comment: app developer 27, may be the make version different to mingw ot Visual Studio version, what do you use to compile? Check your make binary for make the project path and make sure that is correct.

Comment: I never got it working. But finally found this https://github.com/annulen/webkit/releases/tag/qtwebkit-tp5 with which I can use newer webkit and qt 5.8.

Comment: how to fix this in macOS - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72589559/mac-os-warning-project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-webkitwidgets?noredirect=1#comment128228415_72589559

Answer (score 3):

The community builds referenced by Alex are only available until Qt 5.9.
If you want to use newer Qt5 (current version is 5.11), then another option is to port "QtWebKit" to "QtWebEngine".

See: https://wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngine/Porting_from_QtWebKit

Comment: how to fix this in macOS - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72589559/mac-os-warning-project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-webkitwidgets?noredirect=1#comment128228415_72589559

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by copying the webkit and webkitwidgets pri files from a previous installation, 5.5.

`~/Qt/5.5/clang_64/mkspecs/modules/`

Answer (score 1):

For windows, I just downloaded https://github.com/annulen/webkit/releases/tag/qtwebkit-tp5 and copied the folders to relevant Qt installation folder. Now I can use MinGW Qt5.8 with latest webkit. Thanks to Konstantin and all the contributors for this project!

Only one thing to note - I needed to use the release configuration in Qt.

Comment: Can you tell which relevant folder you pasted these files ?

Answer (score 1):

For CentOS, you need to have the `epel-release`, first install that, then install the `qt5-qtwebkit-devel`

```bash
sudo dnf install epel-release
sudo dnf install qt5-qtwebkit-devel
```

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is the combination of two answers, I used what @user1251007 suggested + this command

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5websockets5-dev
```

find this command line here : [link to the stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933425/project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-websockets/43569214#answer-43569214)