# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets

Tags: linux, qt, cross-compiling, qt5, mxe

I'm trying to use MXE (with help from [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170590/building-qt-5-on-linux-for-windows/14170591#14170591)), and I'm getting this error at the `qmake && make` step:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets".
```

What does this mean and what can I do?

Comment: This is falsely marked as duplicate @jon-ericson the question has nothing to do with linked answer. This is about mxe and linked question is about pure linux. The answer doesn't help in this situation.

Comment: @Petr: Could you [edit] the question to make that distinction clear? What is it about MXE that prevents the answer from working?

Comment: MXE is cross-building kit that allows you to build Windows executables on linux. Installing any linux packages, like suggested in answer (which was correctly not accepted as it doesn't really answer this), doesn't help at all. Those linux packages will not affect the MXE installation, and qmake will only look to locations in MXE installation, so it will not find webkitwidgets module even if you install the linux package. That would fix the qmake for linux, but MXE's version of qmake will ignore these linux modules. I don't know how I should edit the question, to me it looks pretty clear :)

Answer (score 7):

As per [this similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699403/unknown-modules-in-qt-webkitwidgets), try installing the corresponding package. Assuming you have a Debian-based system, this is done by entering the following command in a console:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev
```

Comment: This doesn't help, MXE doesn't use any linux packages. It needs windows version of webkit5

Comment: false answer it is about mxe not linux packages, it would be better that the moderator update the title to include mxe keyword, by the way this is also my problem as well

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you're out of luck because recent versions of MXE do not build webkit. Apparently it has symbol conflict with the Qt script library, so the static build is impossible. Use the older MXE version, and don't forget to enable building the webkit in the `src/qt.mk` file.

Comment: Can you suggest which older version is that? Build of 1 version takes about 20 hours, so trying all of them is probably going to take month or more. Does it apply for qt5 as well?