# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: qml quick

Tags: c++, linux, windows, qt, cross-compiling

I've got problems trying to cross-compile an app for windows on Linux Mint x64 following this. (I also got Qt5.4.2 installed.)

[Building Qt 5 on Linux, for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14170590/building-qt-5-on-linux-for-windows/14170591#14170591)

The error shows up when running  [mxe root]/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32.static-qmake-qt5 . Of course I changed [mxe root] to fit the mxe directory.

Any ideas?

My question is pretty similar to this one. [Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415226/project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-webkitwidgets)

It'd be nice not to mark it as duplicate, as was done with that question, because, like @Petr already mentioned in the comments there, the two questions are not related.

Comment: Someone downvoted this without giving a reason. Not nice.

Comment: `The error shows up.` - Which error?

Comment: @MarkJansen title of the question. "Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: qml quick"

Comment: Have you tried all solutions here? https://forum.qt.io/topic/42211/solved-unknown-module-s-in-qt-quick-qml

Comment: @MarkJansen I've seen that. Didn't try anything from there though. Because he's working with Qt creator which I'm not. I was just trying to follow the 'tutorial' on that other SO question. There are some other suggestions there but I couldn't make any sense out of it. I'm pretty new to Qt, deplying, cross-compiling and most importantly to linux itself (though not new to C++) so the whole stuff about modifying . conf files seemed to advanced for me. Thank you for your time trying to help. :)

Answer (score 2):

I've been having the same issue, following the same tuto

I solve it by building qt5 instead of qtbase

```
mxefolder$ make qt5
```

instead of

```
mxefolder$ make qtbase
```

it contains more modules

Answer (score 0):

If you build the Qt from the sources and no Qt5Qml.dll file in bin\ then install the "qtdeclarative" module. Enter to the (your_qt_src_dir)/qtdeclarative and do following (change names to your environment names)

> $ C:\Qt\Qt5.7.0n\bin\qmake.exe -r qtdeclarative.pro
>
> $ C:\mingw32-make.exe
>
> $ C:\mingw32-make.exe install