# Webkitwidgets not found in QT for OS X

Tags: macos, qt

I installed Qt for mac via .dmg installer. I added this to my `.pro` file:

```
QT       += webkitwidgets
```

and then i got this error:

`Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets`

On Ubuntu, [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18699404/1420197) works fine:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5webkit5-dev
```

Also, if I run `whereis qmake` nothing shows up.

Does anybody know how to fix this on Mac OS?

Comment: Are you using QtCreator, qmake from command line, or some other IDE to get qmake run?

Comment: Can you check on the Projects page whether it is using qmake from the .dmg installation? In addition, can you check if the webkitwidgets module is installed propely along with the rest?

Comment: `whereis` is kind of funny in os x. I don't know exactly why, but I think whereis only searches in some hardcoded paths (like /usr/bin , /usr/sbin, /sbin, /bin) and you can't pass flags to it (like you can in linux). I suggest you to use `which`. Is more powerful. Also after you installed qt from dmg the path to qmake should be `yourInstallPath/qt5/5.4.0/bin/qmake`. If you still can't find it, I suggest you to use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install qt and to symlink everything. In homebrew you can find `qt` (4) and `qt5`.

Comment: I'm having the same, no solutions?

Comment: Which version are you running? How did you install what does `which qmake` returns?

Answer (score 3):

you can reinstall qt with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), then make sure to add the flag `--with-qtwebkit` so in total:

```
    brew install qt --with-qtwebkit
```

Comment: Brew responds with: `Warning: qt: this formula has no --with-qtwebkit option so it will be ignored!`

Comment: @Matthias .. I get an error `Error: invalid option: --with-qtwebkit`

Comment: This still fails on macOS Mojave. ```brew install qt@5.7 --with-qtwebkit``` gives ```Error: invalid option: --with-qtwebkit```

Comment: There's also [this doc](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/wiki/Installing-Qt-and-compiling-capybara-webkit#macOS-catalina-1015) on dealing with this issue, except that they tell you to follow the guide for sierra. 
Except that when trying to do that, the install fails because catalina is not supported for something in that process. 

Answer (score 2):

It seems that qtwebkit is deprecated as of version upper than 5.7

Instead of `brew install qt --with-qtwebkit`
Try `brew install qt@5.7 --with-qtwebkit`

It seems that this is last formula version with `--with-qtwebkit` option

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/qt@5.7.rb

Answer (score 1):

In the installer there is a separate point "Qt WebEngine" that you have to check during installation:

[image]