# How to install websockets for Qt 6?

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, websocket, qt6

Already referred below old posts, but its solution of installing `websocket`s didn't work in my Ubuntu 21.10.

- [Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933425/project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-websockets)
- [Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18699403/project-error-unknown-modules-in-qt-webkitwidgets)

This could be probably due to my Qt is 6.2, while the available library is from Qt5, viz. `libqt5websockets5-dev`.

How to install websocket module properly for the Qt6, to fix below error?

> Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: websockets

Comment: How did you install Qt 6.2?

Comment: This page says websockets was removed from 6.0: [https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/whatsnew60.html#removed-modules-in-qt-6-0](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/whatsnew60.html#removed-modules-in-qt-6-0) however its supposed to be back at 6.2: [https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/whatsnew62.html](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/whatsnew62.html)

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I installed from the Qt's online installer. It was not custom installation, but whatever default 6.2 being given. May be I missed the additional libraries as suggested in the below answer. Will give it a try.

Comment: @drescherjm, any idea, why did they intend to even remove the `websockets' library.  Many people should have bem using it for various purpose. Don't they find it useful Or is it buggy?

Comment: You'd have to ask the developers but at a guess I'd imagine it simply wasn't ready for the 6.0 release

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When installing Qt via Qt Maintenance Tool, just go to Additional Libraries and check QtWebSockets. It is available in Qt 6.2.x versions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  You have no idea how long I searched for this answer!