# MAC OS: WARNING: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I am trying to build notepadqq for **MacOS** following the [official doc](https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq/wiki/Compiling-Notepadqq-on-macOS).

while running the make command I am facing below issue -

```
$ make
cd src/ui/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/local/Cellar/qt/6.3.0/bin/qmake -o Makefile /Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/ui.pro PREFIX= QMAKE_CXX=c++ 'QMAKE_CXXFLAGS= ' QMAKE_LFLAGS= LRELEASE=/usr/local/Cellar/qt/6.3.0/bin/lrelease CONFIG+= ) && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f Makefile 
Project MESSAGE: Release build
WARNING: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_de.qm'...
    Generated 348 translation(s) (348 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_es.qm'...
    Generated 365 translation(s) (365 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_fr.qm'...
    Generated 345 translation(s) (345 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_hu.qm'...
    Generated 453 translation(s) (453 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_it.qm'...
    Generated 345 translation(s) (345 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_ja.qm'...
    Generated 344 translation(s) (344 finished and 0 unfinished)
    Ignored 1 untranslated source text(s)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_pl.qm'...
    Generated 348 translation(s) (348 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_pt.qm'...
    Generated 345 translation(s) (345 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_ru.qm'...
    Generated 328 translation(s) (326 finished and 2 unfinished)
    Ignored 17 untranslated source text(s)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_sl.qm'...
    Generated 345 translation(s) (345 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_sv.qm'...
    Generated 359 translation(s) (359 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_uk.qm'...
    Generated 365 translation(s) (365 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_zh.qm'...
    Generated 363 translation(s) (363 finished and 0 unfinished)
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets
make: *** [sub-src-ui-make_first] Error 3
```

Any suggestions on how i can fix the issue? Any help is greatly appreciated (working answer will be accepted or up voted).

1. I am using MacOS Monterey - 12.4 (21F79)
2. As can be seen in the log - i have installed QT(qt/6.3.0) using  brew by following the [link](https://github.com/notepadqq/notepadqq/wiki/Compiling-Notepadqq-on-macOS).

Like Parisa Adviced, i tried with QT5, but same story.

```
C02XP51WJG5J:notepadqq-1.4.0 vsamula$ ./configure 
checking for QT5 qmake... /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.3/bin/qmake
checking for lrelease... /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.3/bin/lrelease
checking for c++... /usr/bin/c++
checking whether c++ compiler builds test program... ok
checking whether c++ compiler supports -std=c++0x... ok
checking whether compiled test program works... ok
checking for make... /usr/bin/make
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/bin/pkg-config
checking for Qt5Core library... not found!
checking for Qt5Gui library... not found!
checking for Qt5Network library... not found!
checking for Qt5WebKit library... not found!
checking for Qt5Widgets library... not found!
checking for Qt5WebKitWidgets library... not found!
checking for Qt5PrintSupport library... not found!
checking for Qt5Svg library... not found!
generate Makefile... Info: creating stash file /Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/.qmake.stash
done

C02XP51WJG5J:notepadqq-1.4.0 vsamula$ make
cd src/ui/ && ( test -e Makefile || /usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.3/bin/qmake -o Makefile /Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/ui.pro PREFIX= QMAKE_CXX=c++ 'QMAKE_CXXFLAGS= ' QMAKE_LFLAGS= LRELEASE=/usr/local/Cellar/qt@5/5.15.3/bin/lrelease CONFIG+= ) && /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make -f Makefile 
Project MESSAGE: Release build
WARNING: Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_de.qm'...
    Generated 348 translation(s) (348 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_es.qm'...
    Generated 365 translation(s) (365 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_fr.qm'...
    Generated 345 translation(s) (345 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_hu.qm'...
    Generated 453 translation(s) (453 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_it.qm'...
    Generated 345 translation(s) (345 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_ja.qm'...
    Generated 344 translation(s) (344 finished and 0 unfinished)
    Ignored 1 untranslated source text(s)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_pl.qm'...
    Generated 348 translation(s) (348 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_pt.qm'...
    Generated 345 translation(s) (345 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_ru.qm'...
    Generated 328 translation(s) (326 finished and 2 unfinished)
    Ignored 17 untranslated source text(s)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_sl.qm'...
    Generated 345 translation(s) (345 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_sv.qm'...
    Generated 359 translation(s) (359 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_uk.qm'...
    Generated 365 translation(s) (365 finished and 0 unfinished)
Updating '/Users/vsamula/Downloads/notepadqq-1.4.0/src/ui/../translations/notepadqq_zh.qm'...
    Generated 363 translation(s) (363 finished and 0 unfinished)
Project WARNING: Qt has only been tested with version 11.0 of the platform SDK, you're using .
Project WARNING: This is an unsupported configuration. You may experience build issues, and by using
Project WARNING: the 12.3 SDK you are opting in to new features that Qt has not been prepared for.
Project WARNING: Please downgrade the SDK you use to build your app to version 11.0, or configure
Project WARNING: with CONFIG+=sdk_no_version_check when running qmake to silence this warning.
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webkitwidgets
make: *** [sub-src-ui-make_first] Error 3
```

Comment: I guess it doesn't compatible with QT 6 or higher you should use QT 5.

Comment: @Parisa.H.R - +1 - i tried with qt5, see the question edited with these logs. It did not work with qt5 either. Any further guidance.

Comment: I try it with qt 5.15 but still had issues, but with qt 5.12.8 it works and build correctly. As I see that project was written with qt 5.6. It doesn't relate to your  OS , it relates to your qt version,  unfortunately QT doesn't have backward compatibility

Comment: Don't forget to `install qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools qtwebengine5-dev libqt5websockets5-dev libqt5svg5 libqt5svg5-dev libuchardet-dev pkg-config` all of these should be installed in qt 5.12.8 or lower

Comment: @Parisa.H.R - gr8 and tx. I am unable to install 5.12.8. Could you guide on how to install it.. `$ brew install qt@5.12.8
Running brew update --auto-update...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).

Warning: No available formula with the name "qt@5.12.8".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.`

Comment: @Parisa.H.R - same is the case with rest of the packages you suggested. `brew install qt5-default qttools5-dev-tools qtwebengine5-dev libqt5websockets5-dev libqt5svg5 libqt5svg5-dev libuchardet-dev pkg-config
Warning: No available formula with the name "qt5-default".
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.`

Comment: Well,  I use Ubuntu i installed it by `.run` file

Comment: @Parisa.H.R - well cool.. i used notepadqq in ubuntu.. it works out of box.. Making it work in MacOS is turning out to be quite a task.. the downloaded dmg is not working.. so am trying to build from source...  lol. Thanks for all your time and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely a version issue. You should try build from a 5.12 source say from https://download.qt.io/archive/qt/5.12/ with version 5.12.8 and lower. The steps for building from source for a mac is at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/macos-building.html.